# In excel, PDF Range of Worksheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is supposed to PDF everything between two worksheets name given below.

The code below when ran says there is a Type mismatch at the line "Sheets(SheetArr).Select". 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub createPdf()

Dim SheetArr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim startSheet As Integer
Dim endSheet As Integer

startSheet = Sheets(InputBox("Sheet name?","CreatePDF")).Index
endSheet = Sheets(InputBox("Sheet name?", "CreatePDF")).Index
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = InputBox("folderPath?", "CreatePDF")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Index >= startSheet And ws.Index <= endSheet Then ' <> "Sheet3" Then
ReDim Preserve SheetArr(i)
SheetArr(i) = ws.Name

i = i + 1
Debug.Print (ws.Name)

End If
Next

Sheets(SheetArr).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, 
Filename:=folderPath & "\test", _
openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

MsgBox "All done with pdf's"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets). The list of sheet names (which should be in double quotes, separated by commas) needs to be wrapped into `Array()`

> Use Sheets (array) to specify more than one sheet. The following
>   example moves the sheets named Sheet4 and Sheet5 to the beginning of
>   the workbook.
>
> VB
>
> Copy Sheets(Array("Sheet4", "Sheet5")).Move before:=Sheets(1)